# Error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" while trying to read & display data from firestore via my react app

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display the data read from my firestore collection, but after getting the data from firestore, I tried using a map function to map & display the data accordingly but it ends up with an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Which may indicate that my events are in a wrong format for the map function or the events are empty.

Here is my code for more clarification:

```
const [events, setEvents] = React.useState();
  // const events = [];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("Events").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      // const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      let events = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>
        events.push({ ...doc.data() })
      )
      console.log(events);
      setEvents(events);
    });
  });

  return (
    <Grid item sm={4}>
      { events.map(event => (
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardHeader
            avatar={
              loading ? (
                <Skeleton variant="circle" width={40} height={40} />
              ) :
              <Avatar
                alt="Ted talk"
                src={event.eventImgUrl}
              />
            }
 .... // code contiues
```

I expect the code to display data for each event accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since loading data from Firestore may take a while, the initial value of `events` is going to be null. From reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214957/how-can-i-pre-initialise-state-with-hooks-in-react), it seems  you can pass in the initial value to `React.useState()`, in which case that line should be:

```
const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
```

By initializing with an empty array (`[]`), the `map` function will just do nothing until the data is loaded.

---

Alternatively, you can only show the grid once the data is loaded, and show some sort of "loading..." message until that time. Something like:

```
if (items) {
  return (
    <Grid item sm={4}>
      { events.map(event => (
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardHeader
            avatar={
              loading ? (
                <Skeleton variant="circle" width={40} height={40} />
              ) :
              <Avatar
                alt="Ted talk"
                src={event.eventImgUrl}
              />
            }
   .... // code continues
}
else {
  return (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think someone could also try adding async await, worked for me just now, but I'm sure there are many other solutions like the above

```
 React.useEffect( async () => {
   const snapshot = await db.collection("Events").get()
    if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log("No Docs found")
    }
      setEvents(
         snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
         return {
         ...doc.data(),
         documentID: doc.id,
         }
      })
   );
    });
  });
```