# How do I set the initial value of a useState to a promise value

Tags: reactjs

I am making a textarea and I need the initial value to be the data gotten from the api fetch

It doesn't even make any sense, but I have no Idea of how else to do it. Help me out!

i have this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(data?.content);
```

I'm fetching "data" from my backend api and it is undefined when the code runs initially because the useState is ran before the data is returned.

```
        <textarea
      className="noteText"
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pre initialise state with hooks in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214957/how-can-i-pre-initialise-state-with-hooks-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial useState should be a value that can be rendered to the user or null, if you want to set the initial state use the useEffect hook setting the value using setValue.

Answer (score 1):

The *initial* value can't be the value from the Promise result if the Promise is constructed in the same component; the component must render before the API call starts (and finishes).

Either conditionally render the textarea only once the API call has finished

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  someApiCall.then(setValue).catch(handleErrors);
}, []);

// ...

{
    value !== undefined && <textarea
        className="noteText"
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
    ></textarea>
}
```

Or set the initial value to the empty string, where you still call `setValue` after the API call finishes. (The text the user types before the API call finishes will be lost - if the API call takes any reasonable amount of time, consider disabling the textarea until then with the `readOnly` prop)

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
  someApiCall.then(setValue).catch(handleErrors);
}, []);

// ...

{
    <textarea
        className="noteText"
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
    ></textarea>
}
```